# How to add Drop Down Menu as Node Attribute

Tags: nodes

I'd like to give users a limited number of selections for a particular node attribute.

I've seen this done in other nodes. How can I add one to the node I'm currently building?

Answer (score 1):

Only as a .bbnode file option. It's called "Dropdown". For instance our "Is Touched" node has one so you can refer to it as an example.